# understanding callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the callback functionality in Javascript. Please find the below code that I have written.

```
var genericFunction=function(arg1, arg2, callback){
  var result=setTimeout(callback(arg1, arg2), 1000);
  console.log('Result >> '+result)
  return result;
}

var sum=function(arg1, arg2){
  return arg1+arg2;
}

console.log(genericFunction(2,5,sum));
console.log('After calling the genericFUnction call.');
```

I am assuming that the the message `After calling the genericFunction call.` should be printed and then later after 10 seconds the value of `7` should be printed. Can you please explain on where I am going wrong?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/raf25msq/)

Comment: Result is being assigned the setTimeout.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/raf25msq/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `callback(arg1, arg2)` at the time `genericFunction` is being executed; its result `7` is being handed to `setTimeout` as the function to execute after 1 second (1000ms is not 10s). Since `7` is not a function, `setTimeout` will ignore it; but it will return a valid timer ID, and that is the result you are getting.

You must pass an unexecuted function into `setTimeout`. You could do `setTimeout(callback, 1000)` - but that would not be useful, as `callback` would be invoked after 1s without being passed any parameters, and its return value would be discarded. So the useful pattern is this:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
  var result = callback(arg1, arg2);
  console.log("result is", result);
}, 1000);
```

(If you don't use `clearTimeout`, you can leave off `var timer =` bit.)

Also, note that you can never ever return a value from an asynchronously executed function (such as one executed by `setTimeout`). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) explains why, and what to do instead.